# Defining static data member of abstract class template inside constructor

Tags: c++, abstract-class, static-methods

I've come across an exam question with this abstract class template definition:

```
template <class MusicPlayer>
class SongAbstract {
 protected:
    unsigned long unique_id;
 public:
    SongAbstract() {
      static unsigned long counter = 0;
      unique_id = (counter++);
    }
    int play() const { return MusicPlayer::play(this->unique_id); }
    void stop() const { MusicPlayer::stop(); }
    unsigned long get_id() const { return unique_id; }
 protected:
    virtual void print_info(ostream& os) const = 0;
};
```

The question in the exam is as follows:
"From the code above it follows that an implementation of the class MusicPlayer is required.
Write a declaration for a class called AndroidMusicPlayer so that the program will run."

The official solution:

```
class AndroidMusicPlayer {
 public:
    static int play(unsigned long id);
    static void stop();
};
```

I'm having trouble understanding what the constructor does and would very much appreciate it if someone could explain the following:

1. What is the purpose of defining the static data member inside the constructor?
2. Why are the methods in AndroidMusicPlayer declared as static? They access data member
   "unique_id," which is not static.

Answer (score 3):

> *What is the purpose of defining the static data member inside the constructor?*

The `counter` variable inside the `SongAbstract` constructor is *not* a member of the class – it is a *local variable*. Being declared as `static` means that its value will be initialized (to zero) only once during the entire program run (the first time that constructor is called). That value is then incremented on each and every call, causing the *actual* member variable (`unique_id`) to be assigned a different value for each object constructed.

> *Why are the methods in AndroidMusicPlayer declared as static? They access data member "unique_id," which is not static.*

Not quite! They are *passed* the **value** of the containing class member variable (well, one is); the confusion here is, perhaps, that the two functions have the same names as member functions of the containing class. The two functions of that `SongAbstract` class call the functions of the same name in the passed `MusicPlayer` class; those latter functions have to be `static`, because there is no instance of their class declared as a member of `SongAbstract` – hence why we pass the `unique_id` as an argument.

(The syntax `MusicPlayer::stop()` is here used to call a `static` class member; similar syntax *can* be used to call a non-static member, but only if the class is a base class of that from which it is being called.)

Comment: It took some digesting, but I got it.  Thanks for the explanation, it helped a lot.